# Associate Cisco-Phone with User via SOAP

Tags: java, wsdl, voip, cisco

Cisco offers the so called "AXL Toolkit" which allows to access functionality provided by the Cisco Unified Communications Manager (CUCM).

A WSDL-File is shipped with the toolkit. Using Eclipse, I tried to create Java-stubs out of it. But this didn't work. It says the file was inaccessible, while I'm having it right on the filesystem...

I would like to associate a phone with an application user. I have a software which does a similar stuff - but sniffing on the network isn't possible, because HTTPS is enforced for AXL-calls.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a tutorial, right on the Cisco website. One can use Apache Axis to transform the WSDL file to working java classes. You just have to modify the WSDL somewhat before.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the information you need to get started:
[Using AXL via WSDL and Java (with Axis)](http://developer.cisco.com/web/axl/wikidocs?p_p_id=1_WAR_wikinavigationportlet_INSTANCE_i9JW&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&p_r_p_185834411_nodeId=803208&p_r_p_185834411_title=Using%20AXL%20via%20WSDL%20and%20Java,Axis)

Then you can just run queries against the database directly (here I'm using the AxlSqlToolkit class from the example code at the link provided):

```
AxlSqlToolkit ast = new AxlSqlToolkit("192.168.10.72", "admin", "admin4cisco");          
String[] res = ast.executeSQL("select pkid from device");      
for (String s : res) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be better link: https://developer.cisco.com/site/axl/learn/how-to/axl-java-sample-application.gsp